# Select different values ​using a radiobutton

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, prepared-statement

Good afternoon I have a problem, I have a table that is filled with information from my database, the problem is that for each row I have a radiobutton with the options yes and no to confirm that information,

```
<div class="container">
            <br><div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><center>LISTADO DE ESTUDIANTES</center></div>
            <h6>*REGISTRO DEL ID O CEDULA DE LOS ESTUDIANTES QUE ASISTIERON ALA TUTORIA<span class="label label-default"></span></h6>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Input" class="col-sm-6 control-label">ID O CEDULA DELOS ESTUDIANTES</label><br>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>PIDM</td>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>ESTUDIANTES</td>
                            <td>EMAIL</td>
                            <td>CÉDULA</td>
                            <td>PRESENTES</td>
                        <tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <%   PreparedStatement st;
                            ResultSet ts;
                            st = co.prepareStatement("select * from uztasistentes where codigo_uztplanif ='" + codr + "'  and codigo_uzgtformularios =3");
                            ts = st.executeQuery();
                            //      Formularios_Connection con = F
                            while (ts.next()) {
                        %> 
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getInt("SPRIDEN_PIDM")%> </td>
                            <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_ID")%> </td>
                            <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_ESTUDIANTE")%> </td>
                            <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_EMAIL")%> </td>
                            <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_CEDULA")%> </td>
                            <td <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="optradio">SI
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="optradio">NO
                                </label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <% }
                        ts.close();
                    %> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the problem is that if I have 20 rows with data, it only allows me to select the answer from a single row, for example I select if in row 1, I go to row 2 I select no and the selection I made in row 1 is automatically deleted Any advice to correct this error. I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an integer variable count so, for every time it iterates, is add plus one, so I rename the radio button with the same name, such as:
Row 0 - `<input type="radio" name="optradio_0">`
Row 1 - `<input type="radio" name="optradio_1">`
Row 2 - `<input type="radio" name="optradio_2">`

Example below:

```
<div class="container">
    <br><div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><center>LISTADO DE ESTUDIANTES</center></div>
    <h6>*REGISTRO DEL ID O CEDULA DE LOS ESTUDIANTES QUE ASISTIERON ALA TUTORIA<span class="label label-default"></span></h6>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Input" class="col-sm-6 control-label">ID O CEDULA DELOS ESTUDIANTES</label><br>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>PIDM</td>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>ESTUDIANTES</td>
                    <td>EMAIL</td>
                    <td>CÉDULA</td>
                    <td>PRESENTES</td>
                <tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%   PreparedStatement st;
                    ResultSet ts;
                    st = co.prepareStatement("select * from uztasistentes where codigo_uztplanif ='" + codr + "'  and codigo_uzgtformularios =3");
                    ts = st.executeQuery();
                    var count = 0;
                    //      Formularios_Connection con = F
                    while (ts.next()) {
                %> 
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getInt("SPRIDEN_PIDM")%> </td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_ID")%> </td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_ESTUDIANTE")%> </td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_EMAIL")%> </td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= ts.getString("UZTASISTENTES_CEDULA")%> </td>
                    <td <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio_<%=count%>">SI
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio_<%=count%>">NO
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <%
                count++;
                }
                ts.close();
            %> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks friend if it worked for me.
Now I have another question how, as all this is in a Form, how I would receive the values ​​that I chose in each row of the radiobutton, how the final name of the example name would be: because I put this and the values ​​are void string radio = request.getParameter ( "optradio");

Comment: and instead this gives error String radio = request.getParameter (optradio _ "+" "+ count +" ")

Comment: As long as you want to use this feature in your list, I suggest that you use ajax to handle it. Are you using ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

The names for the radio buttons should be unique per row, like:

```
name="optradio1"; //for the first row
name="optradio2"  //for the second row
name="optradio3"; //for the third row
```

...